# Unable to access users device in Microsoft Intune using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api, intune

I am trying to access managed devices for a particular user. I have written a code which uses web app to get the authentication code.I am able to see all the users as well as a particular user. But when I try to access the managed devices for user I get 401 unauthorized error. I have checked all the permissions are granted to web app created in azure portal for Microsoft Graph. Here is my code:-

```
try {
    String access_token = getAccessToken();
    String url_str = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user name here}/managedDevices/";

    url = new URL(url_str);
    con = ( HttpURLConnection )url.openConnection();
    con.setDoInput(true);
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    con.setUseCaches(false);
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");
    con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", access_token);
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept","application/json");
    con.connect();

    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( con.getInputStream() ));
    String str = null;
    String line;
    while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        str += line;
    }
    System.out.println(str);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Token Retrieval Code :-

```
private String getAccessToken() {
    String accessToken = "";
    try {
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1); 
        String authorization_url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + Authentication_Constants.TENANT + "/oauth2/authorize/";
        AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authorization_url, false, service);
        ClientCredential clientCred = new ClientCredential(Authentication_Constants.CLIENTID, Authentication_Constants.SECRET);
        Future<AuthenticationResult>  future = authContext.acquireToken(Authentication_Constants.RESOURCE, clientCred, null);
        AuthenticationResult authResult = future.get();
        accessToken = authResult.getAccessToken();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
    return accessToken;
}
```

Is there anything I am missing? Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide the contents of your access token and a sample of how you're retrieving that token?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur-MSFT I have provided the code for how I am retrieving the token. access token is too large to add in here

Answer (score 2):

I work on the Microsoft Intune team, specifically on the integration between Microsoft Intune and Microsoft Graph.

From the looks of the code you give above it looks like you are trying to use app-only credentials to access the API, at the moment the Microsoft Intune APIs only support the use of app+user credentials (i.e. Delegated permissions). In order to access these APIs you will need to authenticate as a user.

If you take a look at the [Microsoft Graph permissions reference for Intune](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference#intune-device-management-permissions) all the permissions are listed as Delegated permissions which require app+user credentials.

If you need to have app-only access to Intune APIs I would recommend adding comments on your scenario on the [Microsoft Intune Feedback site](https://microsoftintune.uservoice.com) under [this item](https://microsoftintune.uservoice.com/forums/291681-ideas/suggestions/18474520-intune-graph-api-should-be-accessible-non-interact).

Thanks

Peter

Comment: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service I am using follwing url wherein admin grants my app consent. Is that ok?  if not please point me to some link for correct authetication for graph to access Intune API.Thanks!