# Microsoft Graph Permissions

Tags: java, azure, permissions, microsoft-graph-api

I have granted my multi-tenant app registered on azure port all the permissions by going to azure portal and clicking on App and Settings -> Required Permissions -> Microsoft Graph.
I gave almost all the permissions for reading users profile and devices and then I clicked "Grant Permissions". I am following the guidelines for generating access token and then access the resources of graph [Get Access Without a User](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service)

I inspected the generated token at https://jwt.ms/ after reading this link from the earlier similar questions posted on stackoverflow [Microsoft Graph 401 Unauthorized with access token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47870502/microsoft-graph-401-unauthorized-with-access-token).

On token inspection it gives me following :-

```
  "roles": [

    "Device.ReadWrite.All",
    "Member.Read.Hidden",
    "Domain.ReadWrite.All",
    "Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy",
    "Application.ReadWrite.All"
  ],
```

I read on the question posted by me earlier [Unable to access users device in Microsoft Intune using Microsoft Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48833704/unable-to-access-users-device-in-microsoft-intune-using-microsoft-graph-api) that we need app + user credentials. But the process I followed makes admin to grant permissions to my app.

When I try to use the generated token using following code :-

```
user_device_info_url = new URL("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/");
    intune_connection = ( HttpURLConnection )user_device_info_url.openConnection();

    intune_connection.setDoInput(true);
    intune_connection.setDoOutput(true);
    intune_connection.setUseCaches(false);
    intune_connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    intune_connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer "+ token);
    intune_connection.setRequestProperty("Accept","application/json");

    intune_connection.connect();

    payload = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( intune_connection.getInputStream() ));

    String json_payload = null;
    String line;
    while((line = payload.readLine()) != null) {
        json_payload += line;
    }
    System.out.println(json_payload);
```

But I am getting unauthorized access 401 for the above url. Any Suggestions?

Also when i used the following code I was able to access the urls except for intune ones.

```
private String getAccessToken_Single_Tenant() {
        String accessToken = "";
        try {
            ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
            String authorization_url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + Authentication_Constants.TENANT + "/oauth2/authorize/";
            AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authorization_url, false, service);
            ClientCredential clientCred = new ClientCredential(Authentication_Constants.CLIENTID, Authentication_Constants.SECRET);
            Future<AuthenticationResult>  future = authContext.acquireToken(Authentication_Constants.RESOURCE, clientCred, null);
            AuthenticationResult authResult = future.get(); // why the future?
            accessToken = authResult.getAccessToken();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        return accessToken;
    }
```

[image: application permissions]
Thanks!

Comment: If you got the token with no user context, what do you expect /me to return? You have to specify which user you want: `/users/user-id-here`.

Comment: @juunas Thanks But i tried https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/" + "username" still its same!

Comment: @juunas and all the urls are working on graph explorer but the only different thing is that here app is asking for permission not user!

Comment: Ahh, you are probably missing a needed app permission (role). By looking here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_get, we can see you need to have one of these: `User.Read.All, User.ReadWrite.All, Directory.Read.All, Directory.ReadWrite.All`. Your token has none of these. So for example, you can add **Read all users' full profiles** (User.Read.All).

Comment: @juunas yes that I know but I followed the permission grant flow as i mentioned in the question. Is there any link apart from azure portal to grant permission? Thanks!

Comment: The easiest way is the Grant Permissions button in the Portal since it does admin consent for the tenant.

Comment: @juunas i did that

Comment: Have you surely added the Application permission "Read all users' full profiles" or one of the other valid app permissions? Remember that delegated permissions don't apply in this case.

Comment: @juunas i have updated the question with application permissions I have given. I think there is some problem with my code!

Comment: And the value of `RESOURCE` is `https://graph.microsoft.com`? I don't really see anything obviously wrong with the setup.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166343/discussion-between-pranay-wankhede-and-juunas).

Comment: @juunas i was using  getAccessToken_Single_Tenant() earlier. I am using the one above it. Thanks!